# Dynamically create scss variable in Angular app

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a variable in my styles.scss file. I am trying to set the variable `$baseColor: #f07f09;` based on a value from a JSON call. Is this possible. I have tried to set it in app.component.ts but I get compilation errors.

The reason I need to do this is to set the button color in my app dynamically. Is there a better solution if this is not possible?

Comment: its better to use different classes with styles for different button states(primary, warning, disabled). And you use those classes conditionally with NgClass

Comment: NgClass is one approach, NgStyle is another. You can't create SCSS variables dynamically, as these no longer exist once the app is built (it's all converted to static CSS). You could, for example, have the `[ngStyle]="myDynamicStyle"` directive everywhere you need it, and set `myDynamicStyle` centrally, in a service for example.